# Android app crashes upon startup

Tags: java, android

I am new to programming and after a while I finally fixed all my errors but now the app crashes on startup! I have not written all of this code by myself but I have edited it. Also when I still received errors the app could start (but not work obviously).
Manifest

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="tk.iWeld.iweld"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="tk.iWeld.iweld.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Activity_Main

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Text2"
    android:inputType="number" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="X"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="_________________________"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Text3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Text3"
    android:inputType="number" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Text3"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:text="="
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
    android:textColorHint="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textRes"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:text="Result"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/resultbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
    android:text="Result" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="89dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Text1"
    android:inputType="number" />
```

And the MainActivity

```
    package tk.iWeld.iweld;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.menu.main);
        }


        public void calculateClickHandler(View view) {
         // make sure we handle the click of the calculator button

         if (view.getId() == R.id.resultbutton) {

          // get the references to the widgets
          EditText text1Text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
          EditText text2Text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
          EditText text3Text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Text3);
          TextView resultText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textRes);

          // get the users values from the widget references

          float text1 = Float.parseFloat(text1Text.getText().toString());
          float text2 = Float.parseFloat(text2Text.getText().toString());
          float text3 = Float.parseFloat(text3Text.getText().toString());

          // calculate the result value

          float totalresult = calculateRESULT(text1, text2, text3);


          // now set the value in the result text

          resultText.setText("" + totalresult);
         }
        }

        // the formula to calculate the result index

        private float calculateRESULT (float text1, float text2, float text3) {

         return (float) (text1 * text2 / text3);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post your LogCat.

Comment: Are you sure your main layout is `R.menu.main`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a mistake in the second line in onCreate():

```
setContentView(R.menu.main);
```

You cannot set a menu as view. If you want to use the main layout, use this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Comment: Oh, yeah I typed layout first but it gave me an error and I saw a main file in menu thats why I typed it like that. But now I realise it wasnt called "main" but activity_main.

Comment: Thanks for the help though, it works now! :D

EDIT: The button doesnt calculate the inputs, do you know whats the matter there?

Comment: Where are you calling `calculateClickHandler`?

Comment: Add this to the button in your xml layout: `android:onClick="calculateClickListener"`

Comment: If it isnt on the screen, then I have forgotten. 
I did that and now it just chrashed when I press the button hm... The guy below said I have to convert the strings is that why? And how do I do that then?

Comment: I cannot tell you what exactly is wrong without the LogCat. I'd suggest opening a new question with the Logcat.
Float.parseFloat should be enough to convert the input to float values. You still have to be careful to only accept numerical input though.

Answer (score 6):

This...

```
android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
```

is SCIENCE FICTION!

The maximum API level today is **19**

Comment: Now he's in the enpasse: whose answer should I accept? I'd say yours, for 2 reasons: 1) because it's deeper than mine. 2) you have less reputation points, so it's right to give some to you istead of me.

Comment: Well, maybe someone finds yet another issue ;)

Comment: For Science Fiction, use 10000 :D ! _"Magic version number for a current development build, which has not yet turned into an official release."_ : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html

Comment: I think you got confused by the SDK release version, which is actually 22.3 ;)

Comment: Haha probably, as I wrote above
"The button doesnt calculate the inputs, do you know whats the matter there?"

Comment: Sure: **you're trying to perform math on strings**! You have to convert those strings to numbers (floats, as I can see from your code)... Strings won't be implicitly converted to numbers.

Comment: What do you mean? I have floats ? Or where exactly?